# Storage allocation for a function

Tags: c

When I define a function like this:

```
void foo(int a, int b) {}
```

1. **when** is the storage allocated?
2. **where** is this storage allocated?

Comment: For the function identified by foo.

Comment: Functions are not specified to occupy storage.

Comment: Ok, but when the compiler sees that definition what does it do?

Comment: The compiler translates the containing translation unit. The translator output may later be collected into a program image.

Comment: No storage will be allocated nowhere by defining a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is something like "what and where is this function after the compiler has done his job":

The compiler translates this definition into assembly code, which is then translated to binary executable. It is not in your *memory* (so there is no "storage allocation"), it is in the *executable file* output by the compiler (`a.out` if you call gcc on linux without any other argument than your input file, or a `.exe` file on windows).

Edit: a bit further, and since your function declares two arguments:

The compiler produces a binary executable, and *this is where your function is*. Now, the executable (when executed) will allocate memory for these arguments (a few bytes on the stack for the two `int`s).

In other words: in your final executable, your function definition is just a bunch of instructions which your CPU can execute. These instructions, however, allocate memory in order to store the two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are allocated on the stack at the moment of the function call. It's called *the frame* of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for a function will be pushed onto the stack before the function is called for 32 bit machines. On 64 bit machines, they will be passed in registers (the first six I think).